# AND operator before LEFT JOIN in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check if the user's first name is equal to "bryan", then join the tbl_usersinfo with tbl_profile. My problem is it returns all the rows in the joined table instead of only the column's first name that equals to "bryan".

here is my query:

```
SELECT i.users_fname, i.users_lname, i.users_gender, i.users_campus,
i.users_email, i.course_code,
p.pic_location FROM tbl_usersinfo AS i 
LEFT JOIN tbl_profile AS p 
ON i.users_fname = 'bryan'
AND i.users_id = p.users_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Take `i.users_fname = 'bryan'` out of the join statement and put it in the where statement:

```
SELECT i.users_fname, i.users_lname, i.users_gender, i.users_campus, 
       i.users_email, i.course_code, p.pic_location 
FROM tbl_usersinfo AS i 
LEFT JOIN tbl_profile AS p ON i.users_id = p.users_id
WHERE i.users_fname = 'bryan'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT i.users_fname, i.users_lname, i.users_gender, i.users_campus,
i.users_email, i.course_code,
p.pic_location FROM tbl_usersinfo AS i 
LEFT JOIN tbl_profile AS p 
WHERE i.users_fname = 'bryan'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT i.users_fname, i.users_lname, i.users_gender, i.users_campus,
       i.users_email, i.course_code, p.pic_location
FROM tbl_usersinfo i LEFT JOIN
     tbl_profile AS p 
     ON i.users_fname = 'bryan' AND i.users_id = p.users_id;
```

The `left outer join` does the following.  It returns all the rows from the first table *even when the `from` clause evaluates to not-true*.  The condition that prevents a row from returning can be on either table.  The result is that a condition on the first table has no effect.

So, the rule is simple.  When you want to filter on the first table, use a `where` clause.  When you want all the rows from the first table but to filter on the second, put the condition in the `on` clause.  You want:

```
SELECT i.users_fname, i.users_lname, i.users_gender, i.users_campus,
       i.users_email, i.course_code, p.pic_location
FROM tbl_usersinfo i LEFT JOIN
     tbl_profile AS p 
     ON i.users_id = p.users_id
WHERE i.users_fname = 'bryan';
```